# How to configure pytesseract to support text detection for non English language in windows 10?

Tags: python, computer-vision, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have tried pytesseract for `English`. It's working fine and generates expected result. But when it comes for other languages (eg: Arabic) other than english, it fails to do so and gives following error:

```
TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\ara.traineddata 
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. 
Failed loading language \'ara\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! 
Could not initialize tesseract.')
```

Tried to get it (`ara.traineddata`) done from `github`, but can't get it done.

Comment: what means you can't download from github?

Comment: I found page [Traineddata Files for Version 4.00 +](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Data-Files.html) and there is link to `ara.traineddata` which I can download. I didn't test this file with tesseract

Comment: after downloading I can do `tesseract image.png output-file --tessdata-dir folder/with/files/tessdata/ -l ara`

Comment: Did as per https://developpaper.com/win10-installs-tesserocr-to-configure-python-to-recognize-alphanumeric-captcha-with-tesserocr/ and installed `testerocr` and `tesserocr`. And Now pytesseract doesn't create any error, and  also doesn't generates any output. Just does clearscreen of python_console. Instead of pytesseract, only tesserocr could do the job.

Comment: `pytesseract` simply execute command like `tesseract image.png output-file  ...` so it  can also get arguments like `--tessdata-dir`  - probably as dictionary with extra options

Answer (score 9):

`pytesseract` is only wrapper on program `tesseract` (OCR developed by Google)

`tesseract` needs files with languages which you can find in its documentation: [Data Files](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Data-Files.html).

You can download [ara.traineddata](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/4.00/ara.traineddata) to some folder and run it with option `--tessdata-dir some_folder` and then it will use `ara.traineddata` from this folder.

If you save `ara.traineddata` in the same folder as you run code then you can use `.` (dot)

```sh
tesseract image.jpg stdout -l ara --tessdata-dir .
```

And the same you can do in `pytesseract` using `config=`

```
import pytesseract

text = pytesseract.image_to_string('image.jpg', lang='ara', config='--tessdata-dir .')

print(text)
```

Eventually you can use environment variable `TESSDATA_PREFIX` for this

```
import pytesseract
import os

os.environ['TESSDATA_PREFIX'] = '.'

text = pytesseract.image_to_string('text-ara.jpg', lang='ara')

print(text)
```

Later you can set `TESSDATA_PREFIX` directly in system or you may try to move `ara.traineddata` to folder with other files `.traineddata`. There should be somewhere `eng.traineddata` which you can try to find with programs/command like `find`

---

I tested it with this image which I found also in documentation: [Command Line Usage](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Command-Line-Usage.html)

[image]

---

**BTW:** `tesseract` normally saves text in file but if you use `stdout` then it displays text in console.

Comment: Btw, are there any ways for Pytesseract to detect the language?